# Final fields state when accessed from subclass

Tags: java

I see a strange behaviour which seems shouldn't happen according to JMM.
I have class B which extends class A, a final protected field in A which is initialized in A constructor accessed by class B in its constructor.

But, in very rare cases I get a NPE when accessed in B.
Any ideas?

Part of the code:

```
class AsyncReplicationSourceGroup extends AbstractReplicationSourceGroup{

    public AsyncReplicationSourceGroup(DynamicSourceGroupConfigHolder groupConfig){
        super(groupConfig);
        createReplicationChannels();  
    }

    protected void createReplicationChannels(){
        //...
        specificLogger.finest("created channel");  // this is where the NPE is thrown from
        //...
    }
}

abstract class AbstractReplicationSourceGroup{

    protected final Logger specificLogger;

    public AbstractReplicationSourceGroup(DynamicSourceGroupConfigHolder groupConfigHolder){
        specificLogger = Logger.getLogger(Constants.LOGGER_REPLICATION_GROUP + "." + _groupConfigHolder.getConfig().getName());
        //...
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal failing example? Otherwise we're guessing.

Comment: what does the code like?

Comment: Could you provide an example which reproduces the exception?

Comment: Could you post a code example? I'm unable to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: "very rare occasions" implies a thread-safety issue to me.

Comment: @nhahtdh - read the question.  The question specifically says the field is initialized in A's constructor.  Besides, it can't be initialized in B because it is declared as final in A, and therefore has to be frozen before any B constructor body is executed.

Comment: I can't post an example since I can't reproduce it. It only happens once every couple of months in our QA. It just feels like an obvious case that shouldn't happen. The example I would have attach would probably look like SoboLAN answer, but as he wrote it doesn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Does AsyncReplicationSourceGroup create a new thread in it's constructor?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you, but could you be running an older version of commons-logging? There have been some errors related to the ClassLoader setting those fields to null. See here: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40212.

Comment: We're not using Commons-logging but Java logging.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to tell for sure from the code posted alone, but if you are sure that the logger itself is null, (and you aren't mistakenly seeing a NPE from inside say, specificLogger.finest), then the most likely explanation is that Logger.getLogger is occasionally returning null for some reason.

I don't think the problem is threading because final fields assigned to in a constructor are guaranteed to be visible once the constructed object is visible as long as no references leak inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really easy to tell from your example, but my guese would be that it has to deal with the logging framework and the train-wreck call to initialize it in the constructor. This is one of the reason logger declarations should always be **private static final**